# How to evaluate the state of LEDs with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, feature-detection

I'm just starting with OpenCV and it is an amazing framework. For my current project, I need to detect the status of a device by looking at its status LEDs. At the moment, I am a bit overwhelmed by all these modules and possibilites, and surely there's always more than one way to get things done. I hope that someone with more experience can show me a strategy on how to tackle the problem.

But let's start, this is what I am talking about. A typical still frame taken from the video stream:
[image: Video input in standard situation]

As you can see, the camera usually sits in the dark and looks at this panel. I marked the important part with the green rectangle. From what I understand up to now, this is what I think might be a first approach. Please correct me, if there's a misconception:

In the end, I do not have one device but several thousands of them, and there are 4 or 5 different device types. Each device type has a typical, fixed arrangement of LEDs, like in the image above. A fixed signature, so to say, but each LED can be in different states.

As the camera position and angle can vary, I think it would be best to not simply define pixels that relate to each LED. I'm thinking of this chain:

1. Identify the device type based on the layout of LEDs in the panel
2. Crop and unskew the image to the area of interest
3. Locate each LED as a single property (each device type has a fixed set of properties (LEDs))
4. Iterate over each property and identify its state (e.g. off/dark, red, green, yellow, white)

So, in other words, I think need to classify an object and then analyze the object's properties (features?) and map them to datapoints with discrete states. The recognition or classification should work with a skewed perspective, so it would probably be neccessary to transform the image into a normalized shape and maybe crop it at the same time, so that you throw away everything outside the green rectangle.

Some of the LEDs may be off, so that the camera won't see them. How would I take care of that when it comes to object recognition?

Just as a sidenote: the image above was taken from a video that I took with my smartphone, which is surely not ideal as the automatic exposure kicks in and the LEDs appear way to bright and produce halos. In the end, I want to use a raspberry camera (v2) with fixed exposure to avoid this. I hope this sample still helps to get the idea across.

Is my general idea ok or is there a better approach? Which techniques and modules would suitable for each of the steps? Thanks in advance for your ideas and comments.

*Update*: [Here's an untouched version of the sample image above](https://imgur.com/download/pDMW4F4)

Comment: As regards doing the object recognition, and some LEDs being off, you may need to wait a while and composite multiple frames choosing a *"lighten"* blend mode so you can get the positions of all LEDs over a certain timeframe. Then, once the display panel type has been recognised, I am assuming it will not change.

Comment: Perhaps this might give you some ideas. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: @Mark: You're right, that's a good idea. And yes, once initialized, the panel type won't change. At fmw42: Interesting article, this might be of interest once I have a normalized image and already know the type and thereby structure of my object.